# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my mvc 4 web application I'm getting the following error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js:115"

on this line we have

```
$("a[data-ajax=true]").live("click", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    asyncRequest(this, {
        url: this.href,
        type: "GET",
        data: []
    });
});
```

I have found many people getting the same error and read posts. Almost all of them recommend reordering the jquery and others scripts , which I have been trying for long time now but nothing seems to remove this error.

Currently I have the css and the scripts in the following order in the head section. Could any one kindly find any issues? thanks

```
<link href="/Content/main/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/UiDatePicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/main/js/General.js"></script>


<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you checked what is in 115th line in _jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js_? And one more thing: `.live()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and was removed in jQuery 1.9.  Use `.on()` instead.

Comment: @Regent this is the call on line 115 $("a[data-ajax=true]").live("click", function (evt). Shall I try to get the latest jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js from any CDN

Comment: Well, interesting... Just replace `.live()` with `.on()` (if it is for dynamic elements, use `$(document).on('click', "a[data-ajax=true]", function (evt) {` or better download newer version of _unobtrusive-ajax.js_

Comment: @Regent thanks. It has solved my problem if you add your comment as an answer then I will accept it

Comment: You're welcome. Well, since it is correct one, I should post this as answer, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.live()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and was removed in jQuery 1.9. You can use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead:

```
$("a[data-ajax=true]").on("click", function (evt) {
```

Or, if elements are added dynamically:

```
$(document).on('click', "a[data-ajax=true]", function (evt) {
```

Note: even though it is possible to fix all these problems in *unobtrusive-ajax.js*, it will be better to download newer version with all these problems been fixed (if this version exists at all, of course).

Comment: Mine had the old version as well.  I had to remove the old ajax package via NuGet and install the new one.  Also F5 your browser as it may be cached.  Even after I had replaced the files, it was still cached in the browser.